# What is the highest credit per common data crystals ratio available in SWTOR?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

### Introduction

My characters are currently holding ALOT of Common Data Crystals (CDC) and since they have better gear than what is available for CDCs, I am looking for ways to transform them into credits.

### Question

**What is the highest guaranteed credits/CDC ratio available, and how do I get it?**

---

***NOTE:** As selling on GTN is not guaranteed, I am looking for options that does not include trading/selling with other players.*

Comment: lockboxes use to be around 600-800k per 1000 basic comms, but they removed the vendors and i'm not sure where you can get lockboxes now for comms

Comment: Because you don't want to trade with players i wont make this an answer but; with 1000 crystals you can buy 33 legendary companion gifts.
Depending on your server you can sell these for quite a bit of cash. average price on my server is around 80-100k a piece, if you would under cut the price to 35k you should sell them almost instantly and will net about 1.16 million which is better than lockboxes.

Comment: @Vahx Yeah, I've seen that option floating around various forums and such. Since prices on GTN may fluctuate a lot from one day to another, I figured vendoring would be a safer bet and, since it is less prone to change (would require a patch change from BW), more suited for this Stack Exchange. But thank you for the tip, I might try it out. :)

Comment: Unfortunatly, even vendors change (as you see with the lockboxes) and thus any question that was ever answered with "lockboxes from vendors" is no longer a helpful answer. If it was answered by an active person, they might edit their answers every now and then to reflect current status of games

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I decided to do some experimenting, while trying out the Level 8 Shield idea provided in another answer and found the following:

1. Buy Versatile Armoring 42 from Level 60 Modification Vendor on Fleet, at 2 Common Data Crystals per Armoring
2. Either wait out the buy back timer (2 hours) or send the Armoring(s) to an alt via in-game mail
3. Sell the Armoring(s) to a vendor for 1660 credits per Armoring

This yields 830 credits per Common Data Crystal if you wait for the timer to runt out, or 829.625 credits per Common Data Crystal if you send them to an alt (as each mail can hold 8 armorings).

#### Answer:

The maximum amount of credits per Common data Crystal is **830 credits/crystal** and is achieved by buying **Versatile Armoring 42** from the Level 60 Modifications Vendor on Republic/Imperial Fleet.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did the shields work out?

Comment: @Vahx See my comment on Nando's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Lvl 8 shields from lvl 8 equipment vendor

Remove the armoring
, then vendor the shield and the armoring

4,4k per 6 CDC

Comment: What's the cost of removing the Armoring from the Shield, and is that already subtracted from the 4.4k?

Comment: For prefered is 52 credits but u sell the armoring for 100

Comment: Other way without removing the armoring is addin a crystal, preferable a 41+ cartel one

Comment: This is about 733k for 1000 CDC

Comment: So, is the 4.4k including the 48 credits you get from removing and selling the Armoring?

Comment: @Nando Could you update the answer to include more information on where to find the vendor and the exact amount you net from each purchase/sale?

Comment: @GunnarSödergren the level 8 equipment vendor is located on the fleet where the old equipment vendors use to be. all the vendors have been removed and replaced by mods/armorings/enhancement vendors but the level 8 section still holds a equipment vendor with some nice basic gear.   As for total profit, see my comment (according to his info, did not test this myself)

Comment: @Vahx Yeah, I figured that's where the vendor would be. Yes, but the profit you state is not exact and, I'm guessing, neither is his: exactly 4400 credits seems an unsually exact number, especially considering the 48 extra credits from the armoring. As such, I don't feel comfortable accepting his answer.

Comment: @GunnarSödergren with the information already provided to you, you could just go and try it out yourself, buy 1 shield and see for how much you can sell it. Then answer your own question and accept it as answer

Comment: @Vahx Ah, yes, I could do that, that's true, but since the information came from Nando, I'd prefer it if they were the one to get the, no pun intended, credit for the answer.

Comment: @GunnarSödergren As a sub, pulling the Armoring costs 35. For everyone, it sells for 100 and the item itself then sells for 4395.  Sub profit is thus 4460, seems like F2P would be 4443.  Adding a crystal allows you to sell the whole thing directly for 4495 without taking out the armoring, so that's a better idea.